# Why do we use 'NULL'?

Tags: c, posix

Why do we use 'NULL' in code below.

Why can't we multiply the seed by an integer?

Sorry I am new to C++.

**CODE**

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/2/time -> _If t is non-NULL, the return value is also stored in the memory pointed to by t._

Comment: Lets reopen - the answer is not "what s null", but "why should we use null" ?

Comment: @elcuco why to reopen? To me, the linked answer is clear to why there is a need to pass NULL

Comment: I think the answer and duplicate both explain why NULL is used very well.

Comment: @elcuco as I said on first comment, I think there is a lack of effort. The question is very clear _Why do we use 'NULL' in code below._ and the answer is clear too. Any futher questions could be easily solved by 10 minutes of search on internet, for example: https://linux.die.net/man/3/srand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) function can write the time to a location provided by a pointer to the function call. This pointer argument can be a null pointer, and then `time` only returns the current time.

On most systems the `time` function returns the number of seconds since an epoch, and as such is a pretty unique integer value to use for [seeding the random number generator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand).

---

The single statement

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

is equivalent to

```
time_t temp_time = time(NULL);
srand(temp_time);
```

Or if we want to use a non-null pointer

```
time_t temp_time;
time(&temp_time);
srand(temp_time);
```